# Cannot save layout page in Moss

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to update a layout page in Sharepoint Designer but when I click Save I receive an Access Denied error. I can see that the layout page is created by the system account. I am in the site owners group so I think I should be able to make modifications to the page.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The page could be checked out by the System Account or never had a published version, also, site owners have limited permissions in the site collection (where the page layouts reside)

Comment: So which permisson do I need to want from site admins?

Comment: Log on the site using an Site Collection Administrator user, go to Site Settings => Galeries => MasterPage and Page Layouts and check if any page layout is pending approval, check-in or the likes.